# sed in bash script with variables returns unterminated error

Tags: sed

I need to replace the first line of a file with the complete content from another file. Does on see what I'm missing?

```
$ cat old.txt
---
foo
bar

$ cat append.txt
---
123
<321>

$ cat process.sh
old=old.txt
append=append.txt
sed -i "1s/.*/$append/" $old
cat $old
```

I'd expect

```
$ bash process.sh
---
123
<321>
foo
bar
```

Though instead I got

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unterminated `s' command
```

when trying to sed with a variable inside my script

while this one works (without variable)
    sed -i "1s/.*/loremipsum/" $old

Comment: Add quotations around the $append variable name.

Comment: @RamanSailopal Thanks. Either:
    
    sed -i "1s/.*/"$append"/" $old

nor this helps:

    sed -i  '1s/.*/"$append"/' $old

Comment: @AikITYM the shell variable `append=$(cat append.txt)` . Just so that you know why you are getting this error is because, `sed` doesn't like newlines on the RHS of a s/// command.

Answer (score 2):

To replace the first line of `old.txt` with the content of `append.txt`:

```
$ sed -e '1{ r append.txt' -e 'd;}' old.txt
---
123
<321>
foo
bar
```

Add `-i` before the first `-e` to do the edit in-place in `old.txt`.

This runs the following short `sed` script on the given file:

```
1{                 # we're on the first line
    r append.txt   # read in the whole of the append.txt file
    d;             # delete the current line
}
                   # (implicit print)
```

On the command line, this is divided into two separate `-e` expression string since the filename used with the `r` command must be terminated by a newline (or the end of the current expression string).

Comment: @don_crissti Oh, blast from the past.